# Importerror after source devel/setup.bash

Tags: ros

OS: Ubuntu 20.04
ROS: Noetic
Gazebo 11

I was able to run my project smoothly and just today, I got ImportError from Python.

When I run `main.py` and the first line is here

```
from mubot_rob_env import MubotEnv
```

It showed

```
'ImportError: cannot import name 'MubotEnv' from 'mubot_rob_env'  
(/home/name/workspace/devel/lib/des_mubot/mubot_rob_env.py)
```

But I checked the file is there. All projects showed the same problem but if I simply copy paste the folder into another machine, everything is fine.

I tried delete `devel` and `build` folders and `catkin_make` but it didn't work. I also print all files under `sys.path` and here:

```
/home/name/workspace/devel/lib/des_mubot
  main.py  
  camke.lock  
  mubot_rob_env.py  
  __pycache__
```

Could anyone know what is wrong? Also, please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: How is the `devel/setup.bash` command mentioned in the title of your question (_Import error after source devel/setup.bash_) related to the problem?